# using HashLocationStrategy and redirectToLogin in MSAL

Tags: angular, msal-angular

i try to redirect to the `MsalGuard` secured url after login with `msal` redirect login while using `HashLocationStrategy` in `angular`.
I activated `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true` in the Module configuration, but MSAL always redirects back to `/`.
I also added `MsalRedirectComponent` to the bootstraping part of the module.

According to the [documentations FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/FAQ.md), `HashLocationStrategy` should work.

did anyone get this to work?